# How to facet phrases in solr?

Tags: solr, facet

Lately i have been trying to apply facet to a field with some values having multiple words(a phrase)? I have been suggested to use shingles but am not sure if that would work as expected as the required phrase should be taken from a given list.

For example: when i apply facet to a field, i get seperate facets for 'Information' and 'Technology' whereas i want it to be a single facet like 'Information Technology'.

**How to facet a particular phrase in a particular field?**

EDIT:
The schema for the required field looks like this:

```
<fieldType name="text_en_splitting_tight" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>

        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true"/>
<filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- this filter can remove any duplicate tokens that appear at the same position - sometimes
             possible with WordDelimiterFilter in conjuncton with stemming. -->
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      </fieldType>
```

The shingles filter doesn't work, as it shows three facets for Information technology: information, technology and information technology.

Comment: Would you post the analyzer from your schema.xml that you are using on that facet field?

Comment: @cheffe, Do check out the analyzer bit of the field type I am using for the required field. I have added it as an EDIT in my question

Comment: why do you have `outputUnigrams="true"` if you don't want to use unigrams?

Comment: @soulcheck: When i turn unigrams to false, it does not index entries which carry only one word like 'physics'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the facet field words are being split in the index, by the analyzers. If you want to facet on fields which has potentially multiple words then we should use the analyzers which does not split the words.  It can be "copy field" in solr so that your indexing process doesn't really change. For example you could have something like below.

`<field name="facet_text_en_nosplit" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>`

Use the above field in your facet query.

Comment: Are you suggesting I use don't use a white space tokenizer? Which other tokenizer can I use in that case? And also, I am not very sure how multi-valued works despite of trying to find its usage in many documentations. It would be kind of you to make your answer a bit more descriptive, I am not able to understand your suggestion.

Comment: For faceting field if you use white space it will facet on each of terms. Which may not be valid for your use case. `string` analyzer uses `solr.StrField` type which is not analyzed but stored as it is. Alternatively you can also use `solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory` for the same.

Comment: In terms of the edit, trying to figure out how to accept it, i got a notification and now it is not visible.

Comment: Multivalued - It is just an array type for that field, there are few restriction and positions gap can be configured. I think it is better to have a another question on the same.

Comment: ok, I've used 2 fields, one which is tokenized for searching and the other which is a string for faceting. That was the content of the edit but with a small example, if it doesn't show up in a few days, will post it again. Thanks a lot for your help!